# List of all customers

Tags: list, magento

I want to create a list of all customers in my custom module I am building, but I can't seem to figure out the problem. I tried this:

```
 public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false)
    {
    $source  = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'firstname');
    return $source->getSource()->getAllOptions($withEmpty, $defaultValues);
}
```

But it gives me an error:

```
Source model "" not found for attribute "firstname"

#0 /var/www/c8do/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model ""...')
```

When I tried to replace firstname with gender, it works properly (give female/male).

Comment: thats the 2nd argument for specify attrbute value. Below answer will work for your situtation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('email');
```

If  you don't need firstname, lastname or email, you can skip this lines.